# Swift - TableView is returning the IndexPath as nil

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am currently trying to code a dynamic table in swift and I am currently unable to get the tablerow to be recognised when I click in a button in my table.

My general intent is this:

I have a table view setup with buttons and labels so that every time I pull a name/serial number from the database it will populate a table row complete with a hidden serial number field along with buttons. When I press one of these buttons such as View or Edit the button will segue to a new page from that button and pass the serial number to that new page.

This table is working okay except for the last bit when it is time to pass the serial number.

In the code below you will see the line
let indexpath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow

When debugging it returns nil instead of the information I need for which row the user has clicked on. I have searched the internet a great deal and I simply have no idea why it would return nil as almost every demonstration of the code in prepareforsegue says that this should work with no problems.

```
import UIKit

class FriendsListTableViewController: UITableViewController
{
    var FriendName = [String]()
    var FriendSerialNumber = [String]()
    var Name: String = ""
    let cellReuseIdentifier = "FriendNameRow"

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tableView.register(FriendsListTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier)

        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

        FriendName = appDelegate.getAllFriendsNames()

        FriendSerialNumber = appDelegate.getAllFriendsSerialNumbers()
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 40
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int
    {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return FriendName.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cellIdentifier = "FriendNameRow"
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! FriendsListTableViewCell

        let row = indexPath.row
        cell.FriendLabel?.text = FriendName[row]
        cell.FriendSerialLabel?.text = FriendSerialNumber[row]
        return cell
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
    {
        let indexpath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
        if segue.identifier == "AddFriendSegue"
        {
            let EditFriendController: EditFriendViewController = segue.destination as! EditFriendViewController

            EditFriendController.IsAddRecord = true
        }

        else if segue.identifier == "FriendViewSegue"
        {
            let FriendController: SingleFriendViewController = segue.destination as! SingleFriendViewController

            let SerialNumberToPass = self.FriendSerialNumber[0]

            FriendController.TheSerialNumber = SerialNumberToPass
        }
        else if segue.identifier == "EditFriendSegue"
        {
            let SerialNumberToPass = self.FriendSerialNumber[0]
            let EditFriendController: EditFriendViewController = segue.destination as! EditFriendViewController

            EditFriendController.TheSerialNumber = SerialNumberToPass
            EditFriendController.IsAddRecord = false
        }
    }

}
```

I also have the table cell code in case that is needed.

```
import UIKit

class FriendsListTableViewCell: UITableViewCell
{
    @IBOutlet weak var FriendLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var FriendSerialLabel: UILabel!

    @IBAction func ViewButton(_ sender: Any)
    {
    }
    @IBAction func EditButton(_ sender: Any)
    {
    }
    @IBAction func DeleteButton(_ sender: Any)
    {
        let TheSerialNumber = FriendSerialLabel.text
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate        
        appDelegate.DeleteFriend(SerialNumber: TheSerialNumber!)
    }

    override func awakeFromNib()
    {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool)
    {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }


}
```

If you require additional information please let me know.

Comment: Maybe a silly question but are you definitely selecting the row? `indexpathforselectedrow ` Works from the `indexPath` of the selected row. You say you want to do it when you tap View/Edit but that wouldn't involve selecting the actual row, just a button within the `UITableViewCell`

Comment: I am selecting a button that appears in the row, yes. It is my understanding that it should select the row as a whole, doesn't the button contain the information on what row it was in? Edit to add: If not, do you know what code I should use to get the row I clicked in?

Comment: I don't believe so. I think `indexpathforselectedrow ` should only be set when you select the actual row. If you want to do it from the view/edit button you'd be better off using a delegate which I can post an answer for if you need me to?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by using a delegate, I have looked up the idea but I don't see how that gets the data I need to the next controller. Please let me know the answer to getting this working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment I would personally use a delegate method from `UITableViewCell`:

Before we start that I'd recommend making your `Friend` data into a model to make life easier, something like:

```
struct Friend {
  var name: String?
  var serialNumber: String?
}
```

This way every-time you need data you only need one `Array<Friend>`. Put a variable in your `UITableViewCell` called friend which you can set everytime it is initialised.

```
var friend: Friend? {
   didSet {
     friendLabel.text = friend?.name
     friendSerialLabel.text = friend?.serialNumber
   }
}
```

At the top of your `FriendsListTableViewCell`

```
protocol FriendsListTableViewCellDelegate {
  func willView(_ friend: Friend?)
  func willEdit(_ friend: Friend?)
  func willDelete(friend: Friend?)
}
```

Put another property in your `FriendsListTableViewCell`

```
var delegate: FriendsListTableViewCellDelegate?
```

You can then call these from your `@IBAction`

```
@IBAction func ViewButton(_ sender: Any) {
    delegate?.willView(friend)
}
@IBAction func EditButton(_ sender: Any) {
    delegate?.willEdit(friend)
}
@IBAction func DeleteButton(_ sender: Any) {
    delegate?.willDelete(friend)
}
```

Back in `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` assign your view controller as the cell's delegate:

```
cell.delegate = self
```

At this point you'll recieve an error because you haven't yet conformed to the protocol in your view controller.

```
extension FriendsListTableViewController: FriendsListTableViewCellDelegate {
  func willView(_ friend: Friend?) {
    // View your friend
  }

  func willEdit(_ friend: Friend?) {
    // Edit your friend
  }

  func willDelete(friend: Friend?) {
    // Delete your friend
  }
}
```

Instantiate your view controller in the delegate methods and push/present it. Add a new property to your pushed view controller and set it using the variable from the delegate method:

```
var friend: Friend?
```

Hopefully you should have everything you need here.

Comment: Thank you so much, that has what I was looking for! I have the data I want being passed now

Comment: Hi Jack.  I just wanted to echo my thanks as I had the same issue in that I had a button on a ViewCell and the tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow was returning nil.  Thanks for a detailed and clear solution.